# When I insert parent entity to repository it inserts duplicate of child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Well, I have strange issue. I have Order, order has cart, cart has cart items collection, which consists of product and it's quantity:

Order:

```
public class Order : DatabaseEntity
{
    public Order(Cart cart)
    {
        Cart = cart;    
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Cart:

```
public class Cart : DatabaseEntity
{                  
    public ICollection<CartItem> Items { get; set; }
    public void AddItem(Product product)
    {
       // Check is there such item, is Items null, update quantity 
       // if there is already such item bla bla
       Items.Add(new CartItem(product));
    }
    ...    
}
```

Cart item:

```
public class CartItem : DatabaseEntity
{        
    public CartItem(Product product)
    {
        Product = product;
        Quantity = 1;
    }        

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }        
}
```

The problem is when I create new order and try to place it I get duplicate product record in database. Why is this happening, I've never faced this issue. What am missing? oO:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakeOrder(MakeOrderViewModel makeOrderModel)
{
    ...
    var cart = Session["cart"] as Cart;
    var order = new Order(cart);
    orderRepository.PlaceOrder(order);
    ...
}
```

Order repository:

```
public void PlaceOrder(Order order)
{
    _repository.InsertOrUpdate(order);
}
```

and repository itself:

```
public class EFDatabaseRepository
{
    ...
    public void InsertOrUpdate<TObject>(TObject entity) where TObject : DatabaseEntity
    {
        var entry = _database.Entry(entity);            
        if(entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // New entity
            _database.Set<TObject>().Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            _database.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        Save();
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        _database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

DatabseEntity is just class with id field

```
public class DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My database context class:

```
public class DataBase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasRequired(ci => ci.Product);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cart>().HasMany(c => c.Items);    

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676) documentation:

> if the entity being added has references to other entities that are
>   not yet tracked then these new entities will also be added to the
>   context and will be inserted into the database the next time that
>   SaveChanges is called.

So you'll need to make sure that the context is tracking your existing entity in the `Unchanged` state before calling `SaveChanges()`.

```
context.Entry(myExistingEntity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Alternatively you could refactor your classes and work with foreign keys instead of at the conceptual level.